# Chart.js Tooltips customization

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I was wondering how to append a symbol like `%` to the tooltips nummeric value?
I've been searching trough the docs but was unable to find it, however, on their main site, they've appended the size value `kB` to the pie [tooltips](http://www.chartjs.org/)

How can I achieve something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can change the tooltip template option :
By default it is :

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>"
```

Change it to be `tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>%"` in the option object you give to create your chart.

I used it because I wanted to show the user a percentage that is not proportional to the size on my chart (My donut chart represent a process, and some process take less time than others so the size isn't the same for all of them)

The exact example you gave was with kb.
Here is the exact code I copy and paste from the index page from Chart.js :

```
var moduleDoughnut = new Chart(canvas.getContext('2d')).Doughnut(moduleData, { 
    tooltipTemplate : "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>kb",
    animation: false 
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Did I miss this in the Docs? I was unable to find that

Comment: It was in the docs, yes, but you'll have to look in the general chart.js options to find it !